# Barman Recovery taking long time

Tags: postgresql, barman

I have Postgres cluster with Barman setup

With Barman backup 1.4TB I am Recovering to another server.
I have DB size is 1.5TB and WAL files size 18 GB.

Using below command for recovery to another server

```
barman recover --remote-ssh-command "ssh postgres@newserverip" main-db-server backup-id /location
```

still its `showing copying required wal files.`

Any one please help

From 2 days still it is running the recovery process

now the /location size  1.7TB and WAL files size 250 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you add the `--target-time` variable in your recovery command. You can run the barman `show-backup main-db-server latest`, to get the details on the latest backup and use the `begin_time` for the `target-time`.

```
barman recover --target-time "Begin time" --remote-ssh-command "ssh postgres@newserverip" main-db-server backup-id /location
```

On the other hand, from Barman 2.3 you can exit recovery when consistency is reached (that is the end of the base backup process) by using `--target-immediate` option (available only for PostgreSQL 9.4 and newer).

```
barman recover -- target-immediate --remote-ssh-command "ssh postgres@newserverip" main-db-server backup-id /location
```